# font awesome icon after the label

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I have a label in my rails app like below.

```
 <%= form.label :label, :class =>'col-sm-3'  %>
```

How can I show an icon of font-awesome `<i class="fa fa-question"></i>` after the label ends?

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<%= form.label :label do %>
  <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I get  undefined variable f error and when I do '      <%= form.label :redeem_loyalty_points, :class =>'col-sm-3' do %>
      <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
      <%- end -%>'

My label goes missing..

Comment: It is still the same. 

'<%= form.label :label, :class =>'col-sm-3' do %>
  <i class="fa fa-question"></i>
<% end %>'

This is what it is..


Not sure why the mark down isn't working

Comment: Instead can I use this image since this is giving me trouble.

'<%=image_tag "qun1.png" ,:height=>'20px',:width=>'20px',:style=>"margin-left: 5px;" %>'

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".